# Android View Binding: When accessing NavHostFragment from included xml layout

Tags: android, layout, navigation, include, fragment

I have activity_main.xml, with `ViewBinding` enabled generates `ActivityMainBinding` Class perfectly. I have another content_main.xml layout which is included in this layout as below:

activity_main.xml

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:id="@+id/main_container"/>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is content_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.varshakulkarni.videorecordwithlyricspoc.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <!--This layout is created to place all the content below the AppBar without overlapping while scrolling.-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
<!-- Update: replace this with androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In `MainActivity` class, while accessing other views like TextViews/Buttons, we can use
`binding.mainContainer.textView.text = "test"` , which works well.

but how do we access `androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment`?

Since the fragments are not normal views, get this error, "Cannot access 'android.widget.fragment'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

MainActivity.kt

```
 binding.apply {
            //Works
            mainContainer.textView.text = "test"
            //throws "Cannot access 'android.widget.fragment'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"
            mainContainer.navHost.postDelayed({
                binding.mainContainer.navHost.systemUiVisibility = FLAGS_FULLSCREEN
            }, IMMERSIVE_FLAG_TIMEOUT)
        }
```

Update: this works when `FragmentContainerView` is used.

Comment: for what purpose you want to access androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment? you can access it by its id +id"nav_host"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To host a navGraph , you should use `FragmentContainerView` instead of `Fragment` with name attribute set to :

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

Comment: Yes I did that, it was fixed. I should have written in it answer. I updated within the question itself!